# Use PHP to list a directory and strip filenames down to integers

Tags: php, arrays, string, file

I'm got a small PHP project that requires using files with numbered names, like so:

```
folder/1.file
folder/2.file
folder/3.file
... etc.
```

What I need to do is get an array of these filenames (easy enough), and then strip them down to integers (eg: array( 1, 2, 3 )). I'm a novice at PHP so I'm not up to speed on it's string functionality.

Any advice you could give me would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to offer a sample input, and the output format you'd expect. And, also, *what you've done so far.*

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$di = new DirectoryIterator('path/to/files');
foreach($di as $finfo) {
  if($finfo->isFile()) {
    $fname = (int)$finfo->getBasename();
    // do something
  }
}
```

$fname inside the foreach loop will contain your integer.

Comment: +1 for using SPL, very nice. I'm going to consider this for any file stuff I do.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks, I've made the switch to SPL for all my FS needs and I haven't looked back.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$files = array();
foreach($scandir('folder') as $file) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
        continue;
    $files[] = (int)$file;
}
```

This casts the filenames to an integer, which effectively changes anything that starts with an integer followed by any characters to just the integer.

e.g.

```
"123text" => 123
"421" => 421
"other" => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
foreach(scandir('/path/to/folder') as  $file) {
    $files[] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $file);
}
```

Comment: regex_replace isn't a function. preg_replace?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
foreach(glob('*.file') as $filename) {
    $array[] = (int)$filename;
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$directory = 'your/directory';
if ($handle = opendir($directory))
{
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($directory . "/" . $file))
        {
            $file_id = (int)pathinfo($directory . "/" . $file,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

This should work fine.